# How to format array in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, formatting

So what I'm trying to do is to use formatting in array and get an output.

```
formatter = ["%{name}","%{height}","%{weight}"]

puts formatter % {name: "Gleb", height: "174", weight: "64"}
```

Can't understand why it's not working.

Comment: _"I'm trying to [...] get an output"_ – what is your expected output?

Comment: I expected: Gleb 174 64

Comment: Then it should be `formatter = '%{name} %{height} %{weight}'`

Answer (score 1):

**How to use formatting in an array and get an output:**

```
formatter.map { |f| f % {name: "Gleb", height: "174", weight: "64"} }
#⇒ ["Gleb", "174", "64"]
```

If the expected output is `"Gleb 174 64"`, one might join the outcome afterwards:

```
formatter.map do |f|
  f % {name: "Gleb", height: "174", weight: "64"}
end.join(' ')
#⇒ "Gleb 174 64"
```

Comment: @EricLeschinski Honestly, when I post an answer I always address the question stated in the OP. Stating “That’s how to use formatting in an array and get an output” in the answer to “How to format array in Ruby?” looks a bit redundant to me. If they want the answer to be deleted, I am fine with that :)

Comment: It looks like your answer is safe from deletion for now, until someone else flags it.  It's a perfectly good answer.  They were probably just flagging it for being code-only.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you tried to make `formatter` a string, not an array, so you forgot the `%` before the `[`:

```
formatter = %["%{name}","%{height}","%{weight}"]
puts formatter % {name: "Gleb", height: "174", weight: "64"}
#=> "Gleb","174","64"
```

Answer (score 0):

### The Problem

Your *formatter* variable must hold a String object. Currently, you're assigning an Array by enclosing multiple strings within square brackets, which designates them as elements of an array literal.

### The Solution

One way to fix your code is to remove the brackets around your array elements and consolidate them into a single string for interpolation. For example:

```
formatter = "%{name}, %{height}, %{weight}"
formatter % {name: "Gleb", height: "174", weight: "64"}
#=> "Gleb, 174, 64"
```

There are certainly other solutions with and without the percent operator, but this should address your specific issue while retaining your desired format string semantics.

Comment: You did more than just remove the brackets, you also removed the quotes.